# Improve nested enum definition

Tags: java, enums

I love using `enum`s, it enhances code readability and usability. But there are cases like this one, that i would like to simplify the "replicated" A and B "enum" construct and functions... is it possible?

```
public static enum KEYS {

    KEYS() {};

    public static enum RSA {

        RSA() {};

        public static enum A {

            ONE (new String[]{...}),
            TWO (new String[]{...}),
            THREE (new String[]{...});

            public final String[] keys;

            A(String[] keys) {
                this.keys=keys;
            }

            public int getVersion(){
                return keys.length;
            }

        }

        public static enum B {

            ONE (new String[]{...}),
            TWO (new String[]{...}),
            THREE (new String[]{...});

            public final String[] keys;

            B(String[] keys) {
                this.keys=keys;
            }

            public int getVersion(){
                return keys.length;
            }

        }

    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: What do you want to simplify?  Also, container classes should be enums.  Also, type names should be UpperCamelCase.

Comment: Common construct and methods (i have a few methods that are replicated...)

Comment: I always define enums in UPPERCASE (it makes them more readable in the code)

Comment: Are `A` and `B` supposed to be `PRIVATE` and `PUBLIC` to match the constructors?

Comment: Also, why write this highly confusing style? `public static enum KEYS { KEYS() {}; ...` looks like you are defining the constructor, but you are actually defining an enum instance KEYS.KEYS.

Comment: Sorry, i edited the code and did not change the constructor names. About the empty enum def. KEYS() {}, i must define it (though, i could call it DUMMY()). Note that this is not present when coding (ex: eclipse does only suggest the nested enums).

Comment: if `A(String[] keys)` were `A(String... keys)` then you could simplify `ONE(new String[] { "foo", "bar" })` to `ONE("foo", "bar")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is currently impossible to have a common implementation of `getVersion()` method reused by various enums (nested or not) because Java makes all enums final (non-extendable) so they can't inherit from each other or other classes. you have to define all methods and constructors for every enum.

(note: it might be possible in future with Java 8 using *defender methods*)